# Storybook displays 'Unable to load template for undefined' error on my Mac, but works on Windows. How do I resolve this?

Tags: storybook

I'm encountering an issue while running Storybook where I'm getting the error message `"Unable to load template for undefined"`. Although Storybook starts properly and I can access it at `http://localhost:4506/`, none of my component stories are displayed, and this error persists.

Since it works perfectly fine on my colleague's Windows machine but fails to work on my Mac, I wonder if it could be some environmental differences causing this behavior and how can I debug it.

Thanks

- I have tried deleting dependencies `"node_modules"` folder and reinstalled.
- Here are some details:
  package.json

```
{
  "name": "aem-maven-archetype",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Generates an AEM Frontend project with Webpack",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "private": true,
  "main": "src/main/webpack/site/main.ts",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE.txt",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --env dev --config ./webpack.dev.js && clientlib --verbose",
    "prod": "webpack --config ./webpack.prod.js && clientlib --verbose",
    "//start": "webpack-dev-server --open --config ./webpack.dev.js",
    "sync": "aemsync -d -p ../ui.apps/src/main/content",
    "watch": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.dev.js --env writeToDisk & chokidar -c \"clientlib\" ./dist & aemsync -w ../ui.apps/src/main/content",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 4506 -s stories/dist",
    "start": "rollup -c -w && webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.dev.js",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run copy:assets && npm run css && npm run compile:modern && npm run compile:legacy",
    "buildWin": "npm run clean && npm run copyWin:assets && npm run css && npm run compile:modern && npm run compile:legacy",
    "buildAem": "npm run clean && npm run copyWin:assets && npm run css",
    "compile:modern": "env BUILD_TYPE=\"modern\" rollup -c",
    "compile:legacy": "env BUILD_TYPE=\"legacy\" rollup -c",
    "css": "sass --load-path=./node_modules --no-source-map ./stories/css:./stories/dist/css",
    "clean": "rm -rf ./stories/dist",
    "story": "npm run clean && npm run copy:assets && npm-run-all --parallel start css storybook",
    "storyWin": "npm run clean && npm run copyWin:assets && npm-run-all --parallel start css storybook",
    "copy:assets": "mkdir ./stories/dist && cp -R stories/assets/ stories/dist && cp -R stories/dist/assets/ src/main/webpack/resources",
    "copyWin:assets": "mkdir .\\stories\\dist && cp -R stories\\assets\\ stories\\dist && cp -R stories\\dist\\assets\\ src\\main\\webpack\\resources",
    "watch:css": "npm run css --watch",
    "watch:dev": "npm run clean && npm run copy:assets && npm-run-all --parallel start watch:css storybook",
    "watchWin:dev": "npm run clean && npm run copyWin:assets && npm-run-all --parallel start watch:css storybook",
    "pretty": "prettier --write ./src",
    "pretty:check": "prettier --check ./src",
    "build:preview": "npm run clean && npm run copy:assets && npm run css && build-storybook -s stories/dist",
    "lint": "stylelint ./src/css && eslint --ext .js ./src",
    "shipit": "npm run build:preview && cp CNAME storybook-static && surge ./storybook-static"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.17.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.3.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-modules": "^0.1.3",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.16.7",
    "@rollup/plugin-alias": "^3.1.9",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^21.0.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-json": "^4.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^13.1.3",
    "@storybook/addon-viewport": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/aem": "^0.0.8",
    "@storybook/html": "^5.3.19",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.7.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.7.0",
    "@whitespace/storybook-addon-html": "1.2.1",
    "acorn": "^6.1.0",
    "aem-clientlib-generator": "^1.4.3",
    "aemsync": "^4.0.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "browserslist": "^4.2.1",
    "chokidar-cli": "^3.0.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^10.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "cssnano": "^5.0.12",
    "eslint": "^8.4.1",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "glob-import-loader": "^1.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "less": "^4.1.2",
    "less-loader": "^10.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.4.5",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss": "^8.2.15",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^4.2.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "promise-polyfill": "^8.2.3",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "rollup": "^2.69.0",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.4.0",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-replace": "^2.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-sourcemaps": "^0.6.3",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^6.0.4",
    "sass": "^1.26.9",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "storybook-aem-grid": "^0.1.3",
    "storybook-aem-style-system": "^0.1.7",
    "storybook-aem-wrappers": "^0.3.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.14.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.2.5",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.3.3333",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.65.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.6.2",
    "jarallax": "^2.0.4",
    "simple-parallax-js": "^5.6.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@adobe/htlengine": "^6.4.1",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addon-storysource": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/client-api": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/theming": "^5.3.19",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "choices.js": "^9.0.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "element-closest-polyfill": "^1.0.5",
    "floatl": "^2.0.1",
    "htl-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "html-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "jquery": "^1.9.1",
    "masonry-layout": "^4.2.2",
    "micromodal": "^0.4.6",
    "object-fit-images": "^3.2.4",
    "swiper": "^6.1.1",
    "ua-parser-js": "^0.7.21",
    "webpack-concat-files-plugin": "^0.5.2",
    "webpack-mix": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 2 version",
    "> 1%",
    "ie 11"
  ],
  "@storybook/aem-cli": {
    "storybookLocation": ".storybook",
    "storybookStoryLocation": "./stories",
    "localPackagePath": ".storybook/aem-library/",
    "appsPath": "../ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps",
    "componentPaths": [
      "../ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/alpha/components"
    ],
    "storybookAEMStyleSystem": true,
    "storybookAEMGrid": true,
    "storybookAEMPageTemplate": true,
    "storybookAEMConfluence": false,
    "storybookAEMFoundation": false,
    "aemContentDefaultPageResourceType": "alpha/components/page",
    "aemContentDefaultPageTemplate": "/conf/alpha/settings/wcm/templates/page-content",
    "aemContentDefaultPageContentPath": "/root/container/container",
    "aemStoryHeadingComponentResourceType": "alpha/components/title",
    "aemStoryHeadingComponentTitleProperty": "jcr:title",
    "storyRoot": "Components",
    "packageGroup": "alpha",
    "packageName": "alpha library.zip",
    "aemContentPath": "/content/alpha-design-system",
    "createAEMContent": true
  }
}
```

.storybook/main.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-viewport/register', '@whitespace/storybook-addon-html', '@storybook/addon-knobs'],
  stories: [
    `../stories/**/*.stories.[tj]s`,
  ],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    config.module.rules.push(
    {
    test: /\.(html)$/,
    use: [{
            loader:'file-loader',
            options:{
                minimize:false
            }
        }]
    },
      {
        
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [
            'style-loader',
            { loader: 'css-loader?url=false'},
            {
              loader: 'postcss-loader',
              options: {
                plugins: [require('autoprefixer'), require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes')],
                
              },
            },
            
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              options: {
                implementation: require('sass'),
                sassOptions: {
                  includePaths: ['node_modules', 'stories'],
                },
              },
            },
          ],
          include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
        },
    
    );

    config.resolve.alias['css'] = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'stories/css/');
    

    console.log('config.resolve.alias', config.resolve.alias);

    return config;
  },
};
```

- macOS Ventura Version 13.4 (22F66)

Since the same code works perfectly fine on my colleague's Windows machine but fails to work on my Mac, I wonder if it could be some environmental differences causing this behavior and how can I debug it.